# C++ : how to access an object created in Form1?

Tags: visual-studio, forms, object, c++-cli

i am new in C++, i'm using VC++ 2008, i have created a form with pictureBox inside with gui design, located in Form1.h.

for code stability, i'm trying to separate beetween gui and processing classes, so i made a new class in process.h which contain code to change image in the pictureBox, the problem is that i cant access pictureBox object from process.h because it's located in different class.

note :
the classname of form is Form1 inside namespace try,
the classname of process is processImage

i have tried to make a setter function named setImage() in class Form1 to set image path of imageBox obj, but i cant make object of Form1 to call that function because Form1 class is not known. for note i have tried to #include "Form1.h" but it still unknown.

is there any solution for my problem?

thanks for your help..

Comment: can you post some minimal code with which you are able to reproduce the problem?

Comment: C++ does not have "forms" -- you must be referring to C++/CLI, which is a completely different language.

Answer (score 0):

Create the class ProcessImage and make an object of this class a member variable of the Form1 class. Create a setImage public method in the ProcessImage class. Whenever the image in the picture box is updated, call this method.

Comment: if i create a setImage method in processImage class, it wont reconize the pictureBox obj that created in Form1 class, so i cant change the image path value

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I could understand your problem, but here's few hints.

You say that you include Form1.h but Form1 is still not visible. It could be the problem when A include B and B include A, that could be solved with forward declarations. Make sure that you don't forget the namespaces.

A.h:

```
#include "B.h"

namespace NamespaceB
{
    class B; // forward declaration
}

namespace NamespaceA
{    
    class A
    {        
        NamespaceB::B m_pB;        
    };    
}
```

B.h:

```
#include "A.h"

namespace NamespaceA
{
    class A; // forward declaration
}

namespace NamespaceB
{    
    class B
    {        
        NamespaceA::A* m_pA;        
    };    
}
```